# AWS Cognito - Programatically get refresh token expiry

Tags: amazon-cognito

Refresh token returned from Cognito is not a JWT token , hence cannot be decoded. Is there a way to get the refresh token expiry or it needs to be maintained at application level.

Comment: thank you for this insights. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to decode a refresh token. If you know the expiration time set in cognito for refresh tokens you can store the time it was generated and calculate based on that.

Answer (score 0):

just to elaborate on the accepted answer, as I had the same question.

- jwt.org cannot decode the refresh token from aws, as it is encrypted

My way around it, is as follows:

- the id token carries "auth_time" (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token.html)
- on login (you could technically do it on refresh as well), I look at that value and add expiration duration to that for a rough estimate
- how to get the expiration duration programmatically? There are probably easier ways to do it, but the sdk-v3 command that worked for me was the 'DescribeUserPoolClientCommand' (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/describeuserpoolclientcommand.html)

pseudo code in typescript (used in nodejs backend code) looks something like this:

```
import { CognitoIdentityProviderClient, DescribeUserPoolClientCommand, DescribeUserPoolClientCommandInput} from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider"
import get from 'lodash/get'

const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({ region: [yourRegion] }) 
const input = {
    UserPoolId: [yourUserPoolId],
    ClientId: [yourWebClientId],
} as DescribeUserPoolClientCommandInput
const command = new DescribeUserPoolClientCommand(input)

const response = await client.send(command)
const refreshTokenValidityUnits = get(
    response,
    "UserPoolClient.TokenValidityUnits.RefreshToken"
)
const refreshTokenValidity = get(
    response,
    "UserPoolClient.RefreshTokenValidity"
)
// result: "days" and "30" for example
```

This is obviously not complete enough to get the exact values, but enough to get anyone started who, like me, might not be as familiar with the aws-sdk yet.